# Как работать с gulp на хостинге

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, npm

Я загрузил сайт на laravel на хостинг через ftp, но у меня там много вещей сделанных во vue. Ранее, чтобы эти вещи обновлять, мне приходилось прописывать `npm run watch`, и после этого обновлялось. 
**Вопрос**. Как мне сделать это на хостинге, чтобы к примеру обновлял vue.js, и автоматически срабатывал gulp и изменения срабатывали. Благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Для node js есть несколько плагинов, которые могут подключаться с ftp и загружать туда файлы.

У меня в проекте используется [EasyFtp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/easy-ftp), он позволяет выбрать каталоги на машине и на сервере для загрузки файлов.

Удобно использовать уведомления для контроля загрузки. Например, [node-notifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-notifier).